# keyboard module does not detect key-press on the first event of Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, python-keyboard

Suppose you have this code.

```
def test(widget):
    print(keyboard.is_pressed("shift"))

t=tkinter.Tk()
b=tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText()
b.bind("<Return>", test)
b.pack()
t.mainloop()
```

Just on the very first try of holding shift and pressing enter, it prints False but after that it works fine (the first time this event is triggered, if shift is held down, it is not detected, but after that it works).

Comment: It's quite likely that the `keyboard` module doesn't play well with `tkinter` since both handle relatively low-level user input events. You can do what you're trying to accomplish here with just `tkinter`, btw.

Comment: With just Tkinter? How? I am not trying to detect both pressing shift and enter, I am trying to prevent something from happening if shift is pressed with enter, so I can't just add shift to the event list.

Comment: That's a different question than what you're asking here — but the (very) short answer is by binding to other event types (or keys).

Comment: This might not work for this exact specific purpose. Since I want to prevent the binding from happening if shift is pressed (or at least a specific part of the function that's bound). Not making shift also trigger it.

Comment: You can bind to the one or both of the shift keys and track their state.

Comment: See [check if modifier key is pressed in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861689/check-if-modifier-key-is-pressed-in-tkinter) for examples.

Comment: This can work to some extent (if I bind the key-release and key-press to track the state, and store it in a variable for example). The problem is Tkinter has no way of detecting whether a key is pressed or not beyond that. For example if shift is pressed then the window goes out of focus and then shift is released, Tkinter wouldn't be able to tell that shift is not pressed when the window comes into focus again.

Comment: You can also detect windows getting and losing focus.

Comment: @Hormoz Try using this: `print(bool(event.state & 0x0001))`. That will check if the shift button is pressed when the event was fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what @martineau pointed out in the comments [check if modifier key is pressed in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861689/check-if-modifier-key-is-pressed-in-tkinter) like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

def test(event):
    # If you want to get the widget that fired the event, use this:
    widget = event.widget

    # Check if the shift key is pressed when the event is fired
    shift_pressed = bool(event.state & 0x0001)
    if shift_pressed:
        ...
    else:
        print("Shift isn't pressed.")

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = ScrolledText(root)
text_widget.bind("<Return>", test)
text_widget.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`event.state` is an integer that holds flags for different keys combinations that are pressed when the event is fired. The `& 0x0001` checks to see if the shift key is pressed when the event is fired.

Comment: Very well answered, IMO.

Comment: @martineau Thanks but you should get most of the credit for posting that link in the comments

Comment: If I get any credit, I think it should be for pointing out why the OP's code didn't work and claiming `tkinter` alone could do what was needed — which you proved by showing exactly how.