# how to detect a key press when a mouse click happened in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas with a rectangle and I want to detect if someone pressed the rectangle together with a key (ie "shift"). [In](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent) [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent) the mouse event can do that with the `key` property. Wondering if tkinter has somehting similar? [I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter) [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211794/how-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-canvas-in-tkinter)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print("pressed", repr(event.char))

def callback(event):
    print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

canvas= Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but it doesn't detect key events, only the mouseclick events work.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: [check if modifier key is pressed in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861689/check-if-modifier-key-is-pressed-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of detecting whether the shift key is pressed or not, you can bind to the `<Shift-Button-1>` event so that the callback is only called if the user shift-clicks on the object.

Here is an example that will display the color of an item when you shift-click on it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_click(event):
    color = event.widget.itemcget("current", "fill")
    label.configure(text=f"item color: {color}")

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="bisque")
label = tk.Label(root)

label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 110, 110, fill="red", tags=("rectangle",))
canvas.create_rectangle(150, 10, 200, 110, fill="green", tags=("rectangle",))

canvas.tag_bind("rectangle", "<Shift-Button-1>", handle_click)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of window with red and green canvas items]

If you want to handle multiple combinations of modifier keys (alt, shift, control, meta, etc) you can bind to `<1>` and examine the `state` attribute of the event object. However, there are platform dependencies that make that problematic. I personally find making individual bindings easier and more straight-forward.

For more on how to use the `event.state` attribute, see [check if modifier key is pressed in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861689/check-if-modifier-key-is-pressed-in-tkinter)

Comment: that works, but when I try to print out the key (so I can distinguish between shift and alt for example like so: `print(event.char)` in only returns `??`, why is that?

Comment: @Tom: you can set up separate bindings for `<Alt-Button-1>`.

Comment: but then i have 5 different bindings for each of the keys I want to address. Is there not an easier way to do so? What is `.char`, `.keycode`, etc. for if they all return `??`.

Comment: @Tom: those are for bindings to keys.

Comment: it looks like the `state` property on the event seems to change when different buttons are pressed in combination with the mouse click. Any idea where I could find what the state property is?

Comment: _"it looks like the state property on the event seems to change when different buttons are pressed in combination with the mouse click."_ yes, that is correct. As for what values it has, I think it's platform-dependent. This is why I recommend binding on specific states.